# Open edx sign in or SSO implementation issue

Tags: openedx, edx

Hi i am trying to implement open edx sign on in my application using open edx api's but failed. How can we create session of open edx by passing user id password of specific user? I am able to register the user but sign in is causing the problem.

Comment: Can you specify better what is the problem and the error you are having ?

Comment: Hi david, i have my website where i am populating the courses from open edx platform which is hosted on azure, so when ever user click on particular courses i am redirecting it to open edx platform, user was already logged in my website so i doesn't want him to again login in edx platform, i want to archive this.